# Getting Discord Authentication Error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, discord

**Client error: POST https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token resulted in a 429 Too Many Requests response: {"code": 0, "message": "You are being blocked from accessing our API temporarily due to exceeding our rate limits freque (truncated...)**

I am getting this error when i am trying to login into my web apllication using discord,I know i am exceeding rate limits i want to increase my rate limit,after sometime it has started working again but i do not want this error again cause i have live customer on my site

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
include base_path('vendor/autoload.php');
use RestCord\DiscordClient;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use App\Notifications\SendCredentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class DiscordLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return Socialite::with('discord')->scopes(['guilds','guilds.join'])->redirect(); //redirect to generated 0auth link
    }

    public function callback(){
        function getTotalMembers($last_id, $membrs_total)
        {
            $discord = new DiscordClient(['token' => getenv('DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN')]);
            if ($last_id == 0) {
                $members = $discord->guild->listGuildMembers(['guild.id' => 815031226699874334, 'limit' => 1000]);
            } else {
                $members = $discord->guild->listGuildMembers(['guild.id' => 815031226699874334, 'limit' => 1000, 'after' => $last_id]);
            }
            $end = end($members);
            $last_id = $end->user->id;
            $membrs_total = array_merge($membrs_total, $members);
            if (count($members) <= 999) {
                return $membrs_total;
            } else {
                return getTotalMembers($last_id, $membrs_total);
            }
        }

        $membrs_total = array();
        $membrs_totals = getTotalMembers(0, $membrs_total);
        $current_guilds_ids=array();
               foreach($membrs_totals as $member){

                           array_push($current_guilds_ids,$member->user->id);
               }


        $user = Socialite::driver('discord')->stateless()->user();

        if(in_array($user->id,$current_guilds_ids))

        {

        
        $accessTokenResponseBody = $user->accessTokenResponseBody;

        if (!Auth::user()) { //handle user login
            $users = User::where(['discord_id' => $user->id])->first();
            if ($users) {
                     if(in_array($users->discord_id,$current_guilds_ids)){

                        User::where(['id' => $users->id])->update([ 'is_binded' => true,'is_verified'=>true]);
                     }

                Auth::login($users);
                return redirect()->route('home');
            } else {
                $users = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
                if (!$users) {
                    $users = new User();
                    $users->name = $user->name;
                    $users->email = $user->email;
                    $password = uniqid();
                    $users->password = Hash::make($password);
                    $users->discord_id = $user->id;
                    $users->discord_email = $user->email;
                    $users->is_binded = 1;
                    if ($user->user['verified'] == 1) {

                        $users->is_verified = 1;
                    }
                    $users->save();
                    $notifyUsers = User::where('email', $users->email)->get();
                    foreach ($notifyUsers as $notifyUser) {
                        $notifyUser->notify(new SendCredentials($notifyUser, $password));
                    }
                    Auth::login($users);
                    return redirect()->route('home');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $users = User::where(['discord_id' => $user->id])->count();
            if ($users == 0) {
                User::where(['id' => $user_id])->update(['discord_id' => $user->id, 'discord_email' => $user->email, 'is_binded' => true]);
                return redirect()->route('home');
            } else {
                User::where(['id' => $user_id])->update(['discord_id' => $user->id, 'discord_email' => $user->email, 'is_verified' => false]);
                $customer_status = User::where(['id' => $user_id])->value('is_customer');
                $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
                $request = $client->get( //perform check
                    'https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds',
                    [
                        'headers' => [
                            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessTokenResponseBody['access_token'],
                        ],
                    ]
                );
                $response = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true); //decode response
                foreach ($response as $key => $value) { //traverse result
                    if ($value['id'] == 815031226699874334) {
                        User::where(['id' => $user_id])->update(['is_verified' => true]);
                        alert()->success('Nice One', 'You are in SMT Proxies Discord.');

                        if ($customer_status == true) {


                            $client = new Client([
                                'headers' => [
                                    'Authorization' => 'Bot ' . getenv('DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN'),
                                    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
                                ]
                            ]);
                            $client->put('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/815031226699874334/members/' . $user->id . '/roles/815046198791503914', []);
                            alert()->success('Nice One', 'You are in SMT Proxies Discord & got customer role');
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        alert()->warning('Sorry You have to join our server first');
        return redirect()->route('login');

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What `grant_type` are you using for the `/oauth2/token` call?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have added the code can you check it please